# AttributeError: 'Programa' object has no attribute 'root'

Tags: kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I'm looking to make a one-screen app. I have 3 text fields and a button. I can't get the values ​​from the text fields.

this is my main.py file

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout

class Programa(MDBoxLayout):
    def calcular(self):
        print("O valor de soma é {}".format(self.root.ids.namee.text))


class TesteApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        pass

TesteApp().run()
```

this is my TesteApp.kv

```
Programa:

    MDGridLayout:
        cols: 1

        MDToolbar:
            title: "SDK Calc"
            left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: app.callback()]]


        MDGridLayout:
            cols: 1
            padding: [22,32]

            MDTextField:
                id: soma
                hint_text: "Soma"

            MDTextField:
                hint_text: "Digitos"

            MDTextField:
                hint_text: "Exceção"

            MDFillRoundFlatIconButton:
                text: "Calcular"
                icon: "calculator-variant-outline"
                on_release: root.calcular()
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
```

I'm getting the error.

```
   File "/python/kivymd/main.py", line 6, in calcular
     print("O valor de soma é {}".format(self.root.ids.namee.text))
 AttributeError: 'Programa' object has no attribute 'root'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access with widgets from your `App` class, you need to use `self.root.ids.blablabla...`, but accessing your widgets in other classes and the story goes like this: you use `self.ids.blablabla...` instead:

```python
class Programa(MDBoxLayout):
    def calcular(self):
        print("O valor de soma é {}".format(self.ids.namee.text))
```

Another note is that although my answer should be correct, you might wanna recheck your kivy code cuz I ain't seeing any widget named `namee` there (Of course if the `namee` is an example of how it doesn't work then it's fine)